# Unable to load Private Key. OpenSSL on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: ssl, openssl, windows-server-2012-r2

I was setting up my MySQL server to use SSL, and followed the guide [here](http://www.chriscalender.com/setting-up-ssl-for-mysql/).

After a creating a ca-key.pem, I encountered a problem: unable to load Private Key.

The only similar problems I could find had to do with 'random state' error and permission errors. None of those applied in my case, as the key is created without problems.

Here's the output after creation:

```
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
.....................................................+++
....................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
```

When I try the next command, I get the following error:

```
unable to load Private Key
3056:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY
```

My commands are exactly as in the guide, except the path to the key. To make sure, I copied the path each time, so no mistakes where made. The file was created, and looked like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[Jibberish]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I later tried the guide at [Amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https.html) (Which where posted in alot of the places with similar problems) with the same result.

I have basically no idea what i'm doing, so any tips would be helpful!

The server is a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 R2, with only MySQL Server and OpenSSL on it.

Comment: Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).